# Python pandas rolling mean while retaining index and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame of statistics for NBA games.  Here's a sample of the data for away teams:

```
                                  away_team  away_efg  away_drb  away_score
date
2000-10-31 19:00:00    Los Angeles Clippers     0.522      74.4          94
2000-10-31 19:00:00         Milwaukee Bucks     0.434      63.0          93
2000-10-31 19:30:00  Minnesota Timberwolves     0.523      73.8         106
2000-10-31 19:30:00       Charlotte Hornets     0.605      77.1         106
2000-10-31 19:30:00     Seattle SuperSonics     0.429      73.1          88
```

There are many more numeric columns other than the `away_score` column, and also analogous columns for the home team.

What I would like is, for each row, replace the numeric columns (other than score) with the mean of the previous three observations, partitioned by team.  I can *almost* get what I want by doing the following:

```
home_df.groupby("team").apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=3).mean())
```

This returns, for example,

```
>>> home_avg[home_avg["team"]=="Utah Jazz"].head()
         3par        ast   blk        drb       efg       ftr        orb
0         NaN        NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
50        NaN        NaN   NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN
81   0.146667  71.600000   9.4  74.666667  0.512000  0.347667  25.833333
```

Taking this, along with

```
>>> home_df[home_df["team"]=="Utah Jazz"].head()
      3par   ast   blk   drb    efg    ftr   orb   stl       team   tov   trb
0    0.118  76.7   7.1  64.7  0.535  0.365  25.6  11.5  Utah Jazz  10.8  42.9
50   0.100  63.9   9.1  80.5  0.536  0.414  27.6   2.2  Utah Jazz  20.2  58.6
81   0.222  74.2  12.0  78.8  0.465  0.264  24.3   7.3  Utah Jazz  13.9  50.0
122  0.119  81.8  11.3  75.0  0.515  0.642  25.0  12.2  Utah Jazz  21.8  52.5
135  0.129  76.7  17.8  75.9  0.650  0.400  37.9   5.7  Utah Jazz  18.8  62.7
```

demonstrates that it is including the current row in the calculation of the mean.  I want to avoid this.  More specifically, the desired output for row 81 would be all `NaN`s (because there haven't been three games yet), and the entry in the `3par` column for row 122 would be .146667 (the average of the values in that column for rows 0, 50, and 81).

So, my question is, how can I exclude the current row in the rolling mean calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) here which *shifts* the index for a given amount to make your rolling window use the last three values excluding the current value:

```
# create dummy data frame with numeric values
df = pd.DataFrame({"numeric_col": np.random.randint(0, 100, size=5)})
print(df)

    numeric_col
0   66
1   60
2   74
3   41
4   83

df["mean"] = df["numeric_col"].shift(1).rolling(window=3).mean()
print(df)

    numeric_col     mean
0   66              NaN
1   60              NaN
2   74              NaN
3   41              66.666667
4   83              58.333333
```

Accordingly, change your apply function to `lambda x: x.shift(1).rolling(window=3).mean()` to make it work in your specific example.